# MongoDb aggregate lookup with large number of documents?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm using MongoDB and trying to do aggregation lookup.
The number of documents in the collection which is being used in "from" attribute of $lookup is in thousands.
Now, this is taking up all the CPU and taking a lot of time to respond.

But if I remove the documents to a couple hundred it's still slow but much much faster than earlier.

Is this normal behavior for aggregation lookup? Should I think of something else if I have a large number of documents?

Please suggest

Comment: Aggregations can take a few milliseconds as long as you have the right indexes. Give an example of your aggregation query, your documents, and list your indexes.

Comment: Thanks! @Robert Seaman
Actually the aggregation that I'm doing is very simple but its still taking minutes.

Let me explain the scenario.
So there are two collections, one is User and other is Notification.
Notification has a field `type`.
I want to get all the users which have notifications of a particular type.
Notification collection has thousands of documents and i have indexed _id and type fields.

what do you think is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: So, you're aggregating across 2 collections? It would be better if you give actual examples of your document structure, your query and your indexes.

Comment: @RobertSeaman Yes, it involves two collections. [Here](https://pastebin.com/6NJ21mvb) is what i get using explain() . And i have index on _id and type fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should find notifications first, then join them with users.
Something like this:

```
db.getCollection('notifications').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                type: "type to search"
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from : 'users',
                localField : 'userId',
                foreignField : '_id',
                as: 'users'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$users"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$users"
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$_id" }
        }
    ] 
)
```